# How I can compare two freespaces?

Tags: c#

I have a text file where I put Space Required, that value (in kB) I extracted with :

```
string SpaceRequired = lines.Where(txt => txt.Contains("SpaceRequired"))
                            .Select(txt => txt.Split('=')[1].Replace("\"", ""))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

and the freeSpace that I need to compare it's here :

```
var drive = new DriveInfo("c");
long freeSpaceInC = drive.TotalFreeSpace;

private static string toReadableSize(long size)
{
    if (size < 1024 * 1024)
        return Math.Round(((float)size / 1024), 2) + "KB";

    if (size < 1024 * 1024 * 1024)
        return Math.Round(((float)size / (1024 * 1024)), 2) + "MB";

    return Math.Round(((float)size / (1024 * 1024 * 1024)), 2) + "GB";
}
```

This comparison I tried to do here :

```
private void Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.StartsWith("C:"))
    {
        /*if (freeSpaceInC >= SpaceRequired)
        {
            this.Visible = false;
            Form2 fm = new Form2();
            fm.ShowDialog();
        }
        else
            MessageBox.Show("You don't have free space");*/
    }
```

but I don't know to do this. I need to compare the value in kB, because in text file I have in kB . How I can do this ?

Comment: You might want to read [this](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/13815/files-size-units-kib-vs-kb-vs-kb).  1 KB is suppose to be 1000 B vs 1 KiB which is 1024 B.

Comment: Yes This is the thing that I can't understand

Comment: You'll have to decide if the KB in your file means 1000 B or 1024 B and don't mix them.

Comment: @juharr As you can see I used 1024, but I saw in answer it's "long reqBytes = 1000 * reqKB;", in this case I need to change 1000 with 1024?

Comment: If that's the definition you are using, then yes.

Comment: you have a better solution ?

Comment: No, Tim has answered your main question.  Whether you decide to define 1 KB as 1000 B or as 1024 B is up to you.

Comment: @juharr you can help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33017852/how-to-modify-a-text-file-if-a-checkbox-is-selected-or-not?noredirect=1#comment53859286_33017852 . Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to parse the string, then you have the kb as `long`. Since [`TotalFreeSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace(v=vs.100).aspx) returns the total amount of free space available on a drive in bytes you have to multiply it with 1000:

```
long reqKB = long.Parse(SpaceRequired);
long reqBytes = 1000 * reqKB;
if (freeSpaceInC >= reqBytes)
{
    // ..
}
```

Comment: @user: you mean _why_ instead of _way_? Because you have kilobytes but you need bytes since `TotalFreeSpace` returns bytes.

Comment: my free space from C is in GB, in this case it's ok your code ?

Comment: @user: [`DriveInfo.TotalFreeSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace(v=vs.100).aspx) returns bytes not GB.

Comment: it's not supposed to be long reqBytes = 1024 * reqKB; ?

Comment: @user If you are defining 1 KB as 1024 B then yes.

Comment: @user: depends on who you ask, MS or HDD manufacturer still claim that 1KB is 1024 bytes but actually it should be 1000 bytes since one kilo is one thousand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte